# What jobs are exempt from the UK £35k requirement?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

In the UK, non-EU workers must earn at least £35k/year or face deportation, as reported in [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2016/mar/12/eu-workers-deported-earning-less-35000-employees-americans-australians), [the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-17204297), or [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/07/07/theresa-may-must-not-be-pm-until-she-rejects-the-policy-of-the-b/).

The Guardian article mentions that nurses are exempt. Are there other exemptions? For example, most post-doctoral scientists earn less than that. Does that mean non-EU citizens cannot come to the UK to work as a post-doctoral scientists?

Comment: It's not productive to rely on the Guardian for information like this. Their immigration stories are more emotional than factual. The requirements for a T2 exemptions are listed in the MAC's shortage list (which is very soon to be revised). If a given job is not on the list, like nurses, then the 35k requirement (which is very soon to be revised) applies and you will not qualify.

Comment: @GayotFow Interesting — and rather shocking — that I apparently couldn't have my job as a climate scientist in the UK if I didn't have an EU passport (and who knows what will happen after Brexit) :O

Comment: Best advice is stay away from the Guardian, stay off the net, and use the MAC and Home Office policy as your guide. Honestly, it will pay off big time if you do that.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm not aware that The Telegraph or the BBC report anything differently than The Guardian, nor can I find a major discrepancy between the three here.  But can you post the MAC thingy as an answer?

Comment: @GayotFow The BBC article btw contradicts your comment; BBC states that PhD-level jobs are exempt but the MAC's shortage list says that physicists are no longer exempt.  If you do have an answer, perhaps you can address this discrepancy?  I'm confused now.

Comment: LOL, what the BBC states (where it concerns immigration news) goes in to the same bucket. I'm OK with being contradicted.  The relevant place for you to look is something like Paragraph 78C of Appendix A **AND** the MAC page at https://www.gov.uk/government/latest?departments%5B%5D=migration-advisory-committee And as I mentioned previously, the MAC received a commission from the Home Secretary last week. So the whole thing is up in the air.  And :) when I wrote about the Guardian, I should have said 'media' :)

Comment: @GayotFow Again, you may post an answer if you have well-sourced useful info :) and btw, this question is not about me.

Comment: Questions about T2 require lots of attention to detail and sometimes must belabour tedious fine print. And I am too whacked out on morphine derivatives (legally prescribed) to even attempt it. Hence comments. Perhaps another day or perhaps someone will promote the various comments into an answer

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Tier 2 guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/eligibility), the current salary requirements are:

> You’ll usually need to be paid at least £30,000 per year or the
>   ‘appropriate rate’ for the job you’re offered - whichever is higher.

What constitutes an "appropriate rate" for various occupations is listed [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-j-codes-of-practice-for-skilled-work). Table 1 lists PhD level occupations. Depending on the field and experience, the required salary for a post-doctoral researcher ranges between £21,600 and £28,000.